# What statistical test should I use when looking at interactions of categorical independent variables and nominal dependent variables

Tags: hypothesis-testing, categorical-data, interaction

I'm not sure what statistucal test to use for my data set.
I'm looking at stress scores compared with part time work at a university. My independent variables are gender, whether they have a job or not and hours worked per week (with 5 different levels) which is all categorical. My dependent variables are physical stress score, social stress score and academic stress score (Nominal as means of their Likert scale results) and academic achievement (categorical on 5 levels)

I'm unsure as to what test to use to look at interactions, as so far I have used chi squares and correlations but nothing to test the interaction. One way ANOVAs and MANOVAs do not work.

Comment: If the physical stress, social stress and academic stress scores are computed as sums or means of a set of items in the corresponding stress scale then you may consider them as scale variables and apply three ANOVA's or a MANOVA for all of them (in case they are positively correlated).

Comment: You might say why ANOVAs and MANOVAs don't work, but if @Epaminondas 's good suggestion doesn't apply, consider ordinal regression a.k.a. multinomial logistic regression.  If that proves too daunting, you could conduct separate analyses by your most concise interacting variable (e.g., separate by gender) and simply descriptively categorize each gender's relationship between hours worked and a given outcome.